# Changing Struct Array from Function (Reading from file)

Tags: c

I have the following struct

```
struct candidates
    {
     char name[20];
     int votes;
    };
struct candidates electionCandidates[];
```

I need to read in from a file and update the names electionCandidates[0] through 7.

I can do so with the following

```
for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        fgets(electionCandidates[i].name, 20, (FILE*)fp);
    }
```

But I need to do this in a function.

I have tried

```
void Initialize(struct candidates* EC[]);

Initialize(&electionCandidates);

void Initialize(struct candidates* EC[])
{
    int i;

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("elections.txt", "r");

    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        fgets(EC[i].name, 20, (FILE*)fp);
    }

    fclose(fp);
}
```

Keeps saying it doesn't see name. Or the whole thing could be wrong. I am not sure.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `struct candidates electionCandidates[7];`, `void Initialize(struct candidates EC[]);`, `Initialize(electionCandidates);`

Comment: The `electionCandidates` declaration at file scope with empty square brackets is dubious; somewhere along the line you need to specify its size.  You should check that the file was successfully opened.  You should always check the result of `fgets()` to detect early EOF.  Your calling syntax with the cast of `fp` to `(FILE *)fp` is superfluous and indicates a lack of confidence.  Passing `&electionCandidates` passes a pointer to an array (`struct candidates (*)[]`) rather than just a pointer as you would if you dropped the `&`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given

```
struct candidates
    {
     char name[20];
     int votes;
    };
struct candidates electionCandidates[];
```

You want

```
void Initialize(struct candidates EC[])
{
    /* ... */
}

Initialize(electionCandidates);
```

When passed as a function argument, the array of structs decays to a pointer to its first element.

Comment: That is working :D I am getting the names loaded now. Thanks everyone

Comment: Be CAREFUL! Read again the comments to your question from **BLUEPIXY** and **Johathan Lefler**. Specifically, the dubious nature of declaring `electionCandidates[];`

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at your `Initialize()` function signature, and turn on your compiler warnings (or pay attention to them if they're already on). You are declaring `Initialize()` to take an array of pointers to `struct candidates`, which is not what you are passing - an array of `struct candidates`. The array decays to a pointer, so `struct candidates *EC` is what your argument should look like (or, alternately, `struct candidates EC[]`, which is equivalent in this case), not `struct candidates *EC[]`. And then call your function without the `&`...

Answer (score 0):

I got it loading the names and everything but I guess I need to point to SPOIL in this? It is not reading or doing the votes/spoiled votes, giving 0 for both.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct candidates
{
 char name[20];
 int votes;
};
struct candidates electionCandidates[7];

void Initialize(struct candidates EC[]);
void Processvotes(struct candidates EC[], int BadVote);
void printResults(struct candidates EC[], int BadVote);

int main()

{

    int i, SPOIL = 0;

    Initialize(electionCandidates);
    Processvotes(electionCandidates, SPOIL);
    printResults(electionCandidates, SPOIL);

}

void Initialize(struct candidates EC[])
{
    int i;

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("elections.txt", "r");

    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)

    {
        fgets(EC[i].name, 20, (FILE*)fp);
    }

    fclose(fp);
}


void Processvotes(struct candidates EC[], int BadVote)
{
        int TVOTE, i;

        FILE *fp;
        fp = fopen("elections.txt", "r");

        fscanf(fp, "%d", &TVOTE);

        for (i = 0; i < 365; i++)
        {
            if (TVOTE == 1)
                EC[0].votes++;
            if (TVOTE == 2)
                EC[1].votes++;
            if (TVOTE == 3)
                EC[2].votes++;
            if (TVOTE == 4)
                EC[3].votes++;
            if (TVOTE == 5)
                EC[4].votes++;
            if (TVOTE == 6)
                EC[5].votes++;
            if (TVOTE == 7)
                EC[6].votes++;

            if (TVOTE < 1 || TVOTE > 7)
                BadVote++;
        }

        fclose(fp);
}

void printResults(struct candidates EC[], int BadVote)
{

    int i, Win = 0, WinSCORE = 0, Runner = 0, RunnerSCORE = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {

        if (EC[i].votes > WinSCORE)
        {
            WinSCORE = EC[i].votes;
            Win = i;
        }

        if (EC[i].votes == WinSCORE)
        {
            RunnerSCORE = EC[i].votes;
            Runner = i;
        }
    }


    if (WinSCORE == RunnerSCORE)
    {
        printf("There was a tie between %s and %s who both got a total of %d votes each. There were %d spoiled votes\n", EC[Win].name, EC[Runner].name, WinSCORE, BadVote);
    }

    else
        printf("%s won the election with a total of %d votes. There was a total of %d spoiled votes.\n", EC[Win].name, WinSCORE, BadVote);


}
```